# Make div box movable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am new to this, so i have following div:

```
<div id="box" style="z-index: 80; left: 400px; position: absolute; top: 50px">
                    <cc2:ExtendedBox ID="Details" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False"
                        CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="PagingDetails" DefaultMode="Edit"
                        OnItemCommand="dvDetails_ItemCommand" ForeColor="#12424" GridLines="None"
                        Style="z-index: 102; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;" Width="350px"
                        HeaderText="Job Details" OnItemInserted="dvDetails_ItemCommand"
                        />
```

I want to make this box movable. Like user can drag it anywhere. I have read on other posts to use jquery, but is there any c# or aspx way to do this?

I also tried adding draggable="true" but that did not work:

```
<div id="box" style="z-index: 80; left: 400px; position: absolute; top: 50px" draggable="true">
```

Comment: No, c# and asps are used server-side, which means that the user/client machine does not have access to them. It must be done in a front-end scripting language i.e. javascript/jQuery

Comment: jQuery UI has a draggable function that's fairly easy to implement. https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @silencedmessage - But i dont want to add jQuery it is big project i am doing just small part in it.

Comment: There's ways of doing it in vanilla javascript as well (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27450504/3033053), but I'm not aware of any way of accomplishing this without some kind of client side script such as js/jquery.

Comment: @silencedmessage: Tried this (https://jsfiddle.net/Xcb8d/848/) not working. Anything i am doing wrong?

Comment: @silencedmessage Got it : https://jsfiddle.net/Xcb8d/850/